# Standard Deviation only using daily values to show on every time chart in Pine Script

Tags: standard-deviation, pine-script

I am trying to make a Standard Deviation overlay using only the daily inputs, and have it overlay that info on any time frame chart.  So, even if I look at an hourly chart, I will still see the daily deviations overlayed on the chart.  I made one that changes with whatever time frame I am looking at.  I started with another public one to make this:

```
study(title="Standard Deviation",shorttitle="SD",overlay=true)
length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(open, title="Source")
sd = stdev(src, length)
piv=open

plotOpen = plot(piv,title="Open",color=black,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR05 = plot(piv+(0.5*sd),title="+0.5", color=red,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS05 = plot(piv-(0.5*sd),title="-0.5", color=red,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR10 = plot(piv+sd,title="1", color=blue,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS10 = plot(piv-sd,title="-1", color=blue,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR15 = plot(piv+(1.5*sd),title="+1.5", color=green,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS15 = plot(piv-(1.5*sd),title="-1.5", color=green,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR20 = plot(piv+(2*sd),title="+2", color=orange,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS20 = plot(piv-(2*sd),title="-2", color=orange,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to make a Standard Deviation overlay using only the daily inputs, and have it overlay that info on any time frame chart.

You can use TradingView's [`security()` function](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_security) for that. That function can load price data from any time frame and/or instrument, including the daily data from the current instrument.

With `security()` your code can thus calculate the daily standard deviation *regardless* of which time frame the script currently runs on.

For example:

```
study(title="Standard Deviation",shorttitle="SD",overlay=true)

length = input(20, minval=1)
src    = input(open, title="Source")

// Load daily stddev
dailyStd = security(tickerid, "D", stddev(src, length))

piv=open

plotOpen = plot(piv,title="Open",color=black,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR05 = plot(piv+(0.5*dailyStd),title="+0.5", color=red,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS05 = plot(piv-(0.5*dailyStd),title="-0.5", color=red,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR10 = plot(piv+dailyStd,title="1", color=blue,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS10 = plot(piv-dailyStd,title="-1", color=blue,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR15 = plot(piv+(1.5*dailyStd),title="+1.5", color=green,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS15 = plot(piv-(1.5*dailyStd),title="-1.5", color=green,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotR20 = plot(piv+(2*dailyStd),title="+2", color=orange,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
plotS20 = plot(piv-(2*dailyStd),title="-2", color=orange,trackprice=true,linewidth=2)
```

Give it a try to see if this approach better serves your goal.

Answer (score 1):

for version 5

```
//@version=5
indicator("Standart Deviation", shorttitle="SD", overlay=true)

length = input.int(30, minval=1)
src = input.source(open,"Source")

//load daily stdev
dailyStd = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",ta.stdev(src,length))
piv=open

plotOpen = plot(piv,title="Open", color=color.white, trackprice = true, linewidth=2)
plotStdResistance = plot(piv+dailyStd,title="RESISTANCE",color=color.red,trackprice=true,linewidth=1)
plotStdSupport = plot(piv-dailyStd,title="SUPPORT", color=color.green, trackprice = true, linewidth=1)
```